# Let $g$ be a non-negative measurable function. Show $\int g(x)^p d\mu = \int_0^\infty p t^{p-1} m_g(t) dt$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $g$ be a non-negative measurable function. For $1 \leq p < \infty$, show that
>   $$\int g(x)^p d\mu = \int_0^\infty p t^{p-1} m_g(t) dt$$
>   where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and we are given
>   $$m_g(t) = \mu\{x | g(x) > t \}.$$

**Attempt**

The first thing I did is show that 
$$\int g(x) d\mu = \int_0^\infty  m_g(t) dt$$
by creating a suitable simple function to approximate the right hand side and showing that it in fact equals the left hand side when we take the $\sup$ over all such simple functions. In attempting to show something similar for $g(x)^p$, note that for $t_i > t_{i+1}$
$$m_{g^p}(t_i^p) - m_{g^p}(t_{i+1}^p) = m_g(t_i) - m_g(t_{i+1})$$
since
$$ t_{i+1} < g(x) \leq t_i \iff t_{i+1}^p < g(x)^p \leq t_i^p.$$

However, how do we achieve the $p t^{p-1}$ term on the right-hand side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $g(x)^p=\int _{0}^\infty pt^{p-1}1_{\{t\leq g(x)\}}dt$. Then integrate $g^p$ and use Fubini's theorem, we obtain : $\int g(x)^pdx=\int _{0}^\infty (\int 1_{\{t\leq g(x)\}}dx)pt^{p-1}dt=\int _0^\infty pt^{p-1}m_g(t)dt$

Comment: It cannot be done with this assumption that $g(0)=0$?

Comment: The first equality wasn't true, I've edited. $\int _{0}^\infty pt^{p-1}1_{\{t\leq g(x)\}}dt =\int _0^{g(x)}pt^{p-1}dt=g(x)^p$ and not $g(x)^p-g(0)^p$. Sorry.